# Servlet changes aren't taking effect

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to make changes to my Session servlet and they won't take effect. Basically I've written this:

```
isUserConfirmed = false;

if(isUserConfirmed) { do code }
else { do code }
```

For some reason isUserConfirmed is coming back true although I've give it a static value of false.

I'm trying to debug something and I've run into this rather annoying problem.

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your reply..

Comment: well you are saying that some code isn't working, so why not show it and maybe we can figure out why

Comment: Can you please post your code here? Are you sure that the code you have changed is actually build properly, and compiled class is at its place (if you build it manually)?

Comment: Did you try to clean the application and redeploying?

Comment: I think it's a caching issue. I've put an obvious if statement in that will ALWAYS return false as I've set it with a static value of false. But it thinks isUserConfirmed equals true when ive hard set it to false. Theres no point in posting the rest of the code because its got nothing to do with that, its the boolean variable that is the problem.

Comment: Absolutely right. That means there is issue with building and deploying. It does not have new code changes. That might be because of build cache (If building it from editor directly and deploying it to server in editor), OR if building servlet manually then the updated class file is not at its properly place which is WEB-INF/classes/<package_structure_if_there_is_any>/YourClass.class.    Try cleaning your application and rebuild and clean server cache. This may solve your issue.